# What Does :: Mean?

Tags: c#, .net

Exactly as the title says, I think I was looking at c# code when I saw this a while back, I never took much notice of it, but what does `::` Mean in c#. I think I saw something like `myVar::Process.Start()`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad

Comment: One would use it if you have a method or property named the same as a property you want to use.  As in, you have a namespace **Taylor** and a method named **Console**  Using **::** you can specify what namespaces to search in, i.e. **global** to search for **Console**, on the **System** level, rather than **Taylor.Console**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is the [namespace alias qualifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad) - if you use namespace aliases:

```
using config = System.Configuration;

...

var value = config::ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Somthing"];
```

It helps disambiguating when you have types with the same name in the same scope.

For example - if you have several `Leg` classes (one for furniture, one for the leg of a journey), and both are in imported namespaces, with the result that when you use `Leg` in your code the compiler can't tell which one you mean, then if you have a namespace aliases to the namespaces, you can use `<alias>::Leg` to refer to the exact type you mean.

There is a default [alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d) `global` for the global namespace.

Comment: Thank you, you cleared this up. I'll mark you as the answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Note, that if there's _no_ conflict of names, if you have a `using` alias to a **namespace**, like above, then it's equivalent to say `config::ConfigurationManager` and `config.ConfigurationManager`. So it's a matter of preference in that case. If you have a using alias to a **type** (say a class), then you can never use the `::` operator for that.

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales - if you have a question about python, you should ask about python. This question is tagged C# - why would I give an answer about python (which I am not familiar with) on a C# question?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales - don't spam people via comments. Being question blocked doesn't make it right.

Answer (score 9):

It's in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/htccxtad(v=vs.80)):

> The namespace alias qualifier (::) is used to look up identifiers. It is always placed between two identifiers, as in this example:

```
global::System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
```

[How to: Use the Namespace Alias Qualifier(C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/c3ay4x3d(v=vs.80)) is probably also useful.

Answer (score 1):

You would use **::** if you has a method or property named the same as another, in a lower namespace.  For instance:

```
namespace Taylor 
{ 
 public Console {get; set;}
}
```

So let's say you wanted to use **Console.WriteLine();**

Without using the `global::System.Console.WriteLine();`  It is, by default, going to be using `Taylor.Console`  simply because it is pointing to `this`

It basically makes it differentiate among namespaces, to one you specify; the most common being: `global` (the lowest level).

This example is a little redundant, as System.Console will point to it anyway.  Viewing Oded's example sheds some light on how to use `::` while also using it dynamically.