# What's the difference between using :: and typing the fully qualified namepace?

Tags: c#, .net

I recently asked a question: [What Does :: Mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870508/what-does-mean)

Then today, of course I ran into that exact problem. Going off the top of my head I think I was using both the System.Timers and System.Threading namespaces. As far as I can remember they both have a class called Timer. Now that's irrelevant what I want to know is what's the difference between the following:

```
Using myalias = System.Timers;
myalias::Timer myTimer = new myalias::Timer();
```

and

```
Using System.Timers;
System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
```

I hope this is clear enough, I just want to know why use :: when you can just type the namespace out is it just to save typing incase you have a lot of nested namespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about difference, it's *a way* of using the types that are in collision.

If you use some type

```
namepsace My.System.Pro
{
   public class Project{}
}
```

begin to use some other project that has

```
namepsace His.System.Pro
{
   public class Project{}
}
```

Two types `Project` are in collision, so istead of writing *fully qualified* name, you assign a *alias* to yuor, and/or to his namespace. This is just for comfort, for coding style.

Comment: @TaylorGibb: I just completed my answer, check it out please.

Comment: But I could still use both My.System.Pro.Project as well as His.System.Pro.Project ? Right?

Comment: @TaylorGibb: no if you write in your code just `Project pro`, compiler will give a error, cause it has no idea which *concrete* type you refer to, `My.System.Pro.Project`, or `His.System.Pro.Project`, so you need to specify *fully qualified name* of the type.

Answer (score 2):

:: becomes useful if a number of scenarios. Saving typing is just one, and indeed in most cases the fully qualified name is sufficient.

A key use is in code-generation, where referring to global::System.whatever can save embarrassment, especially in the case where somebody makes a poor choice of calling a type / nested-type / property `System` - in which case System.Whatever no longer refers to what you expected it to, but global::System.Whatever *does*.

A more subtle one: consider two libraries, a.dll and b.dll - that for some reason both contain a Foo.Bar.SomeType - here, we can use "extern alias" to talk separately about both types, by having different top-level aliases (rather than global::) to name them.

Answer (score 0):

Both would product the same underlying code, the question is of code readability

Comment: I don't think that is something anybody but you can answer.

Comment: Im talking about in general, what is considered better coding practice, I mean I been coding for about a month, I wouldn't know.

Comment: I agree with @BoltClock, but from my experience, when the same naming collision occures more than once in the same cs file, I usually add an alias, otherwise I use the full namespace

Answer (score 0):

They produce the same code, but the alias thing is for lazy power-devs that know it exists and don't want to go through the trouble of writing all those long qualifiers.

**Edit:** I personally prefer the long qualifiers because the aliases make code hard to track. It's the source code version of the [yo-yo problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_problem)

Answer (score 0):

The alias is just a way to shorten the fully-qualified version. Which is better is a matter of readability. Usually, fully-qualified types take up more space than they need to, so a compact way of specifying the type is usually preferred.